# Trouble with compiling errors

Tags: c, pointers, network-programming, compiler-errors

I am getting some compilation errors I can't figure out, and although I'm sure they're quite stupid I can't find an answer that helps me much through other channels.

Problem 1:   (These are a part of a TCP protocol)

```
error: ‘TH_SYN’ undeclared (first use in this function)
error: ‘TH_ACK’ undeclared (first use in this function)

tcp.tcph_flags = TH_SYN;
tcp.tcph_flags = TH_ACK;
```

Problem 2:

```
error: conversion to non-scalar type requested

const int one = 1;
char buffer[PCKT_LEN];
struct sockaddr_in sin;
struct ipheader ip;
struct tcpheader tcp;

ip = (struct ipheader) buffer;                      /* ERROR POINTS HERE */
tcp = (struct tcpheader) buffer + ip.iph_ihl *4;    /* AND HERE */
```

Problem 3:

```
warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast

case 'i': dip = inet_addr(optarg);
          dstip = (optarg);  /* ERROR POINTS TO THIS LINE */
          break;
```

Now I hope I've copied enough relevant information on the errors for you to be able to help, but if I've left something out let me know. For problem 1, I believe I am missing a header file of some sort but I don't know which. Problem 2 and 3 are pointer issues, but I'm not sure why they aren't correct. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- For the first problem, include the header defining `TH_SYN` and `TH_ACK`. On my system it's `netinet/tcp.h`
- For the second problem, turn `ipheader` and `tcpheader` into pointers
- For the third problem I think you need a `strtoul` but I'm unsure

Comment: @Woodrow Douglas thanks to both of you! The thing is though, I had already included `<netinet/tcp.h>`. I'm using Backtrack5, is it possible that the header files are different?

Comment: Just did and it gives me this: `./dumbnet/tcp.h:#define TH_SYN 0x02 /* synchronize sequence numbers */
./netinet/tcp.h:#  define TH_SYN 0x02
`
I don't suppose the space between # and define in netinet is the problem?

Comment: @youjustreadthis Maybe you're including `netinet/tcp.h` too "late".

Comment: right at the top of the code along with all the other header files.

Comment: nevermind, I'll create a separate question if I don't figure it out later today. thanks for the help =P

Answer (score 3):

For problem 1, you need

```
#include <netinet/tcp.h>
```

For problem 2, `struct ipheader` should be `struct ipheader *` in both your declaration and cast, as well as `struct tcpheader` should be `struct tcpheader *`

For problem 3, optarg is a pointer, and needs to be dereferenced, so refer to it as `*optarg`